# UserControl DependencyProperty.Register ERROR

Tags: wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

```
public class ImageData
{
    public int ImageIndex { get; set; }
    public ImageSource ImgSource { get; set; }
    public string SourceUrl { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateTime { get; set; }
    public string ImageTitle { get; set; }
    public string ImageClass { get; set; }
}


public partial class ImageListControl : UserControl
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageDataListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ImageDataList",
            typeof(System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<ImageData>), typeof(ImageListControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("NO DATA"));

    public ImageListControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<ImageData> ImageDataList
    {
        get { return (System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<ImageData>)GetValue(ImageDataListProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageDataListProperty, value); }
    }

}
```

---

I the use UserControl registered DependencyProperty error.Why can not I register DependencyProperty ? I don't know what is wrong. Please help me ,Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FrameworkPropertyMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557298.aspx)'s constructor takes an object as the first parameter. This object is the default value of your property. So the problem is that the string `"NO DATA"` cannot be converted into `ImageData`. You can either provide `null` as the parameter or provide some appropriate instance of `ImageData` whichever looks more valid to you. I prefer `null` though.

Answer (score 1):

In the fourth parameter to DependencyProperty.Register, you are passing in property metadata that specifies a default string value for the property of "NO DATA" which cannot be converted to ObservableCollection.  Change the line to be:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageDataListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ImageDataList",
        typeof(System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<ImageData>), typeof(ImageListControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());
```